# How do I ask my Safari browser users to user google chrome for my HTML website?

Tags: javascript, html

Actually my HTML website is not compatible with safari browser so i want to make all the safari users ask to use Google chrome for better user interface experience. Please can anyone provide me the code or set of code that i can use. I need a HTML code, NOT PHP. Need Help !!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser

Comment: Do you even know what JavaScript is? Since you think all provided code is PHP?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO does not write code for you so you should not ask such questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari/') > -1) {
    window.alert("Please use Google Chrome for a better user interface experience on this website.");
}
```

since you believe the above code is PHP, you could also use this:

```
if(Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0) {
    window.alert("Please use Google Chrome for a better user interface experience on this website.");
}
```

Comment: This is PHP and i want to insert it in HTML !!

Comment: @DinzAwtani This is actually javascript.

Comment: Thankyou so much @Daan

Comment: No problem! If this answer solved your problem, it would be greatly appreciated if you could mark it as the 'accepted answer'. This helps other users with the same problem to easily find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
if (isSafari == true){
  alert('Please use Google chrome instead of Safari!');
}
```

Comment: This is PHP and i want to insert it in HTML !!

Comment: Huh! Its not PHP. Its javascript! You can put it in HTML file. In header or anywhere inside the body tag.

Comment: @DinzAwtani Just like the code I provided, this is actually javascript.

Comment: Thankyou so much @XahedKamal

Comment: You are welcome. You should mark the correct solution as the answer of our question!